# Javascript for not IE 7

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented `addthis` javascript in my code.

But if I open my page in IE 7, it will not work.

So, I am trying to add that script only if the browser is not IE 7

First I wrote this code and it works.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hihi');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

That code works and the page will show `hihi` in `IE 7` but not in other browsers.

Now, I want to reverse this and make the page show `hihi` only if the browser is not `IE 7`

I tried

```
<!--[if !IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hihi');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to select a non-IE7 browser, or all IE versions except for IE7? There's a huge difference between these two.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that to non-IE browsers, it just looks like a normal HTML comment and therefore the script is not included. One option is to create a variable that you check against in your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isIe7OrLower = false;
</script>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    isIe7OrLower = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("IE 7 or lower: " + isIe7OrLower);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, you solution is the best. Can I extent my query and ask the tip to show and hide the code `<li><a></a><script></script></li>` depends on `isIe7OrLower` ?

Comment: @william: I'd suggest doing that by giving your `<li>` an ID and hiding it using the CSS `display` property. For example: `<li id="test">Stuff</li><script type="text/javascript">if (isIe7OrLower) { document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";</script>`

Comment: Yes, I can hide the `li` tag. What abt the `script` tag? this is the real script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4edf705f715577b0"></script>` Can we remove it too?

Comment: @william: You could do it with `document.write` instead, which I consider an acceptable solution but some would disagree. Be aware that `document.write` does not work in XHTML documents, and also that you should only call `document.write` while the document is loading. Example code: `if (!isIe7OrLower) { document.write('<li><script src="..."></script></li>'); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
```

Comment: What does kinding not working mean? All conditional comments will hide the script from all non-ie browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hihi');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the type of browser with javascript using the `navigator object` ([w3schools try me](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all)).

```
var Browser = {
  Version: function() {
  var version = 999; // we assume a sane browser
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
    // bah, IE again, lets downgrade version number
    version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
  return version;
}
}

if(Browser() > 7){
alert("hi hi");
}
```

Source : [Check IE version with javascript](http://obvcode.blogspot.co.nz/2007/11/easiest-way-to-check-ie-version-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need `()`, check the [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[if !(IE 7)]`

> Subexpression operators. Used in conjunction with boolean operators to create more complex expressions.

[See Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('hihi');
    </script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```